# questions about windows azure 90 day trial

Tags: azure

Just a quick question about the windows azure trial.

If i get the windows azure 90 day trial

- will it show on my debit card?
- could i be charged at all, i heard they put a spending limit on all trial accounts, however can you still be charged at all, even if you dont take the spending limit off?
- the larger the vm you make (small to large for example) the shorter
  it will run as it uses more compute hours?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide credit card, but won't be charged, so it won't show in statement.
If you excess you limit, they just will disable your account, but won't charge anyway.
Not sure about third question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a credit card for verification purposes, but you won't be charged unless you explicitly switch to pay-as-you-go.  And yes, the larger VM you created the quicker it will use up the free trial credit.  The current trial gives you $200 or 30 days, whichever you hit first.